# Clarification of ideas concerning a quotient space.

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces, quotient-spaces

Suppose I have a vector space $V$, and I identify $x\in V$ with $\lambda x\in V$, where $x\neq 0$ and $\lambda>0$, $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

I'm confused about two things: (1) Can I define a norm on $V$, say $\|\cdot\|$ ?

Looking into this I see that $\|\lambda x\|=\|x\|$, but for a norm isn't it required that $\|\lambda x\|=|\lambda|\|x\|$ ? Or maybe because I've identified $x$ with $\lambda x$ then vectors of the form $\lambda x$ with $\lambda\neq 1$ are not permitted, so there is no problem ?

My second question (2). My "identification process" above reminds me of things like $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ where we have elements being equal modulo $n$ in that case. In my case we would have for example $(1,2)\equiv(2,4)$. Is there a quotient group like symbol for my space with identified elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A norm is a thing we sometimes define on a vector space. The quotient space you describe is not a vector space; it has no concept of addition.  So one can't even begin talking about a norm on it.

The quotient space is naturally identified with unit sphere in $V$, since each equivalence class contains exactly one element with unit norm. This leads to a natural notion of metric on this space: just use the distance between the corresponding points of the unit sphere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But why is there no concept of addition? E.g. I currently perform addition like this: $(1,2,3)+(3,0,5)=(4,2,8)\equiv(2,1,4)$ ?

Comment: But (1,2,3) is the same as (2,4,6), and adding (2,4,6) to (3,0,5) you get a vector that's not a multiple of (2,1,4). So the result is not well-defined.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Finally, how would one symbolically express the identification of this quotient space with the unit sphere in $V$?

Comment: Something like $(V\setminus \{0\})/\sim\ \approx S^{n-1}$ via the map $[x]\mapsto x/\|x\|$.